# Rushing through the end of הלל

Tags: hallel

Why is it that everywhere I ever davened, when saying [הלל](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallel) 
, after "...אנא ידוד", people speed through "...ברוך הבא" and especially by יהללוך.

Why is this? Is it some Halacha? Segula?

Its not like thats the end of davening. There is still leining and Mussaf afterwards.

And then they finish their speedy הלל and the חזן starts קדיש and I'm still in middle of הלל and can't answer אמן.

*(The one time a year they don't speed is on Sukkos, when the Rebbe spends half an hour shaking the Lulav and Esrog by הודו לידוד, then I have plenty of time to finish הלל with Kavanah! [But then, of course, after shaking, everyone starts speeding to the end! But by that time, I'm already done for 15 minutes!])*

It seems like a race! Who can finish first?

Comment: People rush Hallel more than they rush everything else?  I hadn't noticed (says the person who is always still in the silent amidah when the chazan starts the repetition).

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not a halachah or segulah! It might be that once there are no more tunes or recitations to wait for, people just have a tendency to "finish it up." It could also be that you are always a little slower than the chazzan/congregation, but don't notice any friction until the end because of the melodic "buffers" interspersed throughout Hallel. Come to think of it, the real reason is probably because the rest of Hallel has a tune to which people like to sing it, but Boruch Habah and especially Yehalelucha are basically just recited, so they take less time.

Comment: "It could also be that you are always a little slower than the chazzan/congregation," - Then perhaps you have the answer to this question: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/190/experience-based-advice-for-focusing-and-slowing-down-prayers

Comment: *Somoene's* got to be the slowest in shul!

Comment: It could also be that you are always a little slower than the chazzan/congregation... But I SPEED to finish with everyone else. They just ZOOOOM right through it, its impossible to keep up! I don't daven very slowly...

Comment: Did you ever try asking THEM why they do it?

Comment: Incidentally, some Lubavitch shuls sing "keli ata v'odeka elokay arom'meka", allowing one plenty of time to finish before the congregation if he so desires.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it is a rush to be able to say "Amen" to the Chazzan at the end of Yehalelucha. If you don't beat the Chazan to the punch, then you'll still be in the middle of the bracha. So practical considerations, rather than halacha or segula.

Comment: That just pushes the question further down the road - why does the chazzan say it so quickly that people feel the need to rush?

Comment: josh waxman, you are basically asking my question. But its not only the Chazan. Everyone seems to do it!

Comment: The reason why I gave this answer a "minus", is because it really isn't an answer...

Comment: josh waxman, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your contribution to this discussion! We'd love to have you as a fully registered user, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Comment: "But its not only the Chazan"
right. but the Chazan doing it causes the rest of us to do it. as to why the chazan does it, maybe for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Also, the Chazan is finishing it up, at a somewhat *normal* pace. But he is not pausing a little to let people finish first. Therefore, everyone is rushing to finish before him.

Comment: This is one of the few places where even Ashkenazim will say amen when ending the same bracha at the same time since it's the end of a set of brachos.

Comment: but what if you don't finish at precisely the same time, but half a second later? then you are in the *middle* of a bracha. would you interrupt?